# Python xlrd Show only 100 Row

Tags: python, xlrd

I have an excel file that contains 400,000 rows. I just want to show only first 100 and I'm using Python and xlrd.

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_file)
worksheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

print(worksheet.nrows)
```

This code is reading the whole file. I just want to read only first 100 row

Comment: You can try iterating and printing the rows, but this will give the output in list form:

```python
for i in range(100):
    print(worksheet.row(i))
```

Comment: Ok thanks, Is it natural to load too long? because of the file size is 90mb, 7-10minutes too loadd

Comment: Yeah, xlrd takes the entire workbook in memory and 400k is a good amount of data but 7-10 minutes seems pretty high.

Comment: Is there other way that will only show 3 column of each row?